# Rad grid localization

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, radgrid

How do i localize the text that is written in the bottom when pagination is done in the radgrid. For Example text which displays the page number Page No. 1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in which context you use the RagGrid, but there is how I changed the pager strings for RagGrid in my ASP.NET project:

```
protected override void OnItemDataBound(GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Localize pager.
    if (e.Item is GridPagerItem)
    {
        var pager = (GridPagerItem)e.Item;
        var label = pager.FindControl("GoToPageLabel") as Label;

        if (label != null)
            label.Text = "Page #:";

        label = pager.FindControl("PageOfLabel") as Label;

        if (label != null)
            label.Text = string.Format(", total: {0}", label.Text.Substring(label.Text.IndexOf(' ')));

        label = pager.FindControl("ChangePageSizeLabel") as Label;

        if (label != null)
            label.Text = "Items per page:";

        var button = pager.FindControl("GoToPageLinkButton") as Button;

        if (button != null)
            button.Text = "Go to this page";

        button = pager.FindControl("ChangePageSizeLinkButton") as Button;

        if (button != null)
            button.Text = "Change page size";

        return;
    }

    base.OnItemDataBound(e);
}
```

I assuming that there is almost same way to do it for WinForms. Also you can subscribe to ItemDataBound event instead of overriding the protected method.

Comment: cant find the controls. isnt there some other way to do it.

Comment: Note that example above is valid for ASP.NET. Also note that there is a set of modes for pager exists. For each mode there will be different default control names.
See: [Telerik example #1](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grdaccessingdefaultpagerbuttons.html) and [example #1](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-accessing-default-pager-buttons.html)

Comment: or some way to implement through javascript

Comment: The text of the items needs to be in need to be in local language selected by the user on the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are RadControls for various presentation frameworks, you should be more specific.

If you're using AJAX ASP.NET, it should be something along PagerTooltipFormatString in RadGrid.PagerStyle (see [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-localizing-tooltips.html)).